# Cannot reinitialise DataTable in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm confused on how can I infuse my json format from django to Datatable , what I tried below using  loop in the script

`{% for json in company %}` `<script>..</script>`  `{% endfor% }`

but It persist error  `DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.`

Is there's any wrong with my implementation, Am I correct? to fetch all data from views.py json to datatable , is there anyway?

**Javascript**

```
{% block footer_scripts %}
{% for row in company %}
<script>

$(function () {
  var dt_basic_table = $('.datatables-basic'),
    dt_complex_header_table = $('.dt-complex-header'),
    dt_row_grouping_table = $('.dt-row-grouping'),
    dt_multilingual_table = $('.dt-multilingual'),
    dt_basic;

  // DataTable with buttons
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------

  if (dt_basic_table.length) {
    dt_basic = dt_basic_table.DataTable({
      ajax: assetsPath + 'json/table-datatable_example.json',  //I want to infused here the json format from views.py 
      columns: [
        { data: '' },
        { data: 'id' },
        { data: 'id' },
        { data: 'full_name' },
        { data: 'email' },
        { data: 'start_date' },
        { data: 'salary' },
        { data: 'status' },
        
        { data: '' }
      ],
      columnDefs: [
        {
          // For Responsive
          className: 'control',
          orderable: false,
          searchable: false,
          responsivePriority: 2,
          targets: 0,
          render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
            return '';
          }
        },
        {
          // For Checkboxes
          targets: 1,
          orderable: false,
          searchable: false,
          responsivePriority: 3,
          checkboxes: true,
          render: function () {
            return '<input type="checkbox" class="dt-checkboxes form-check-input">';
          },
          checkboxes: {
            selectAllRender: '<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">'
          }
        },
        {
          targets: 2,
          searchable: false,
          visible: false
        },
        {
          // Avatar image/badge, Name and post
          targets: 3,
          responsivePriority: 4,
          render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
            var $user_img = full['avatar'],
              $name = full['full_name'],
              $post = full['post'];
            if ($user_img) {
              // For Avatar image
              var $output =
                '<img src="' + assetsPath + 'img/avatars/' + $user_img + '" alt="Avatar" class="rounded-circle">';
            } else {
              // For Avatar badge
              var stateNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
              var states = ['success', 'danger', 'warning', 'info', 'primary', 'secondary'];
              var $state = states[stateNum],
                $name = full['full_name'],
                $initials = $name.match(/\b\w/g) || [];
              $initials = (($initials.shift() || '') + ($initials.pop() || '')).toUpperCase();
              $output = '<span class="avatar-initial rounded-circle bg-label-' + $state + '">' + $initials + '</span>';
            }
            // Creates full output for row
            var $row_output =
              '<div class="d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center user-name">' +
              '<div class="avatar-wrapper">' +
              '<div class="avatar me-2">' +
              $output +
              '</div>' +
              '</div>' +
              '<div class="d-flex flex-column">' +
              '<span class="emp_name text-truncate">' +
              $name +
              '</span>' +
              '<small class="emp_post text-truncate text-muted">' +
              $post +
              '</small>' +
              '</div>' +
              '</div>';
            return $row_output;
          }
        },
        {
          responsivePriority: 1,
          targets: 4
        },
        {
          // Label
          targets: -2,
          render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
            var $status_number = full['status'];
            var $status = {
              1: { title: 'Current', class: 'bg-label-primary' },
              2: { title: 'Professional', class: ' bg-label-success' },
              3: { title: 'Rejected', class: ' bg-label-danger' },
              4: { title: 'Resigned', class: ' bg-label-warning' },
              5: { title: 'Applied', class: ' bg-label-info' }
            };
            if (typeof $status[$status_number] === 'undefined') {
              return data;
            }
            return (
              '<span class="badge ' + $status[$status_number].class + '">' + $status[$status_number].title + '</span>'
            );
          }
        },
      
      ],
  });
    $('div.head-label').html('<h5 class="card-title mb-0">Admin</h5>');
  }
});


</script>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock footer_scripts %}
```

**This is my Views.py** I used json to convert data to jason format and fetch it inside datatable.

```
from main.models import ( Company,Unit )
import json 
def company(request):
    qs_json = serializers.serialize('json', Company.objects.filter().order_by('name'))
    context = {
        'company' : qs_json,
    }
    return render(request, 'admin/company.html', context)
```

**Updated:Table headers**
my tbody is on my script so should i used loop there?

```
   <div class="card">
        <div class="card-datatable table-responsive pt-0">
        <table class="datatables-basic table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Remarks</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should be inside the table and not inside the script tag

```
<table>
 <thead>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 {% for row in company %}
 <tr>
    <td>{{row.name}}</td>
    <td>{{row.address}}</td>
 </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody> 
</table>
```

> % for json in company %} .. {% endfor% }

This is basically initialising your Datatable on ".datatables-basic" div for every item in the company array hence the error

> DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Cannot reinitialise DataTable

If you want to use Ajax to populate your datatable you need to create a view that returns **JsonResponse** and then make a request to that view through the ajax option of Datatable, check out their official [docs](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax) for more info, this code is pulled from there.

```
 $('#myTable').DataTable( {
ajax: {
    url: '/api/myData',
    dataSrc: 'data'
},
columns: [ ... ]
```

} );

Comment: but I don't have a tbody in my table, the design is on the script tag tha'ts why i put loop in the script tag

Comment: What's the best thing to do? when fetching data from django to script? it is possible?

Comment: Your django template tag loop should be inside the tbody as i mentioned. And then initialize the datatable through JavaScript.